# RTSP client_port definition?

Tags: c#, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am having problem in getting response for RTSP Describe option using Socks protocol.

I have other question regarding this issue. I just found that `RTSP client_port` range sometimes work for example with: `client_port=56147-56148` and sometimes `client_port=3347-3348`.

I really have difficulties to understand even after reading all wiki couple of times, so what exactly the `client_port means` and `where do we find it`, because there is no this kind of explication in wiki of RTSP.

```
 stringBuilder.Append("Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=3347-3348\r\n");
```

So can it be random port range or it should be some specific number?

Comment: Many standard protocols setup communication parameters on a main channel  RTSP uses a standard HTTP connection as a main channel.  Additional UDP/TCP channels can be spawn for data transfer.  WIKI is just summarizing the specification RFC 7826 : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7826.  Most protocols are controlled by the IEEE using RFC specifications which are difficult to understand.  The RFC are written by committees whose members are people who use the standard and may have different options since it is difficult to get people who work for different companies to agree on one standard.

Comment: Page 69 of the RFC has a good explanation of the port definition.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure if I miss but as you claim  page 69 doesn't contain any info I asked 'client_port so thx anyways'

Comment: Looks like example is new version.  You have older version.  RFC says : Two new addressing parameters have been defined: src_addr and
         dest_addr.  These replace the parameters "port", "client_port",
         "server_port", "destination", and "source".

Comment: @jdweng ok but in response there is nothing like you mention, i can get server_port but not dest_addr OR should I simple replace that even that in response body there is nothing like this?

Comment: Your server is the older version so use what is in the response.

Comment: @jdweng ok thanks man